# What is the "book of the wars" mentioned in Numbers 21:14?

Tags: exodus, referent-identification, numbers, moses

Numbers 21:14 (NKJV)

> 14  Therefore it is said in the Book of the Wars of the LORD:  “Waheb in Suphah,   The brooks of the Arnon,

Could the book of wars be the one Moses wrote & recited to Joshua (Exodus 17:14-16)?

This book quoted above seems a little bit mysterious

1. What is the book of wars
2. Who wrote this book?

Comment: Are you looking for unsubstantiated claims by early commentaries?

Comment: Both biblical & extra biblical sources

Comment: Extra questions: What is the war that this passage talks about? How does it relates to the well? Why were they singing for the well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same passage in the Septuagint reads, "14 On account of this it says in *the* scroll war (i.e. war scroll) of the LORD, Zoob set ablaze, and the rushing streams of Arnon. 15 And the rushing streams he established to settle Ar, and it lies near the boundaries of Moab." - TABP

In context, the fragmentary passage references another scroll to provide support for defining this boundary of Moab and Amorite lands. As previously pointed out, the identity of that scroll is speculative. The use of the tetragrammaton of the burning bush tradition provides evidence that this was an contemporary Israelite scroll known to Moses that might have contained a poem, song, or historical record, but not written by a prophet.

Dieter

Comment: "The use of the tetragrammaton of the burning bush tradition provides evidence that this was an contemporary Israelite scroll." The use of the name Yahweh is not restricted to the Israelite tradition but to the Midianite tradition as well, and may even have originated with them. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahweh. So i would be reluctant to jump to this conclusion.

Comment: @Dieter This was in fact Luzzatto's argument against Mendelssohn that I noted above.  In his words:

Comment: ל כן יאמר בספר מלחמות ה׳ – כתב רמבמ״ן שמשה מביא כאן מה שהיה כתוב בספר ההוא, להיות זה לעדות לישראל שלא נכנסו בגבול מואב; ולא אמר כלום, שהרי לדעתו הס׳ ההוא היה מלאכת איש יהודי, והיה כתוב בו היא הבאר אשר אמר ה׳ למשה, גם שם הס׳ (ספר מלחמות ה׳) מורה שהוא מלאכת איש יהודי, כי שם בן ארבע אותיות הוא מיוחד לאלהי ישראל, וא״כ מה ראיה מדברי הס׳ ההוא? והנכון שאין זה (כדעת ראב״ע) ספר בפני עצמו, אבל ספר הוא כאן (כדעת רש״י ורשב״ם וקלעריקוס) שם הפעולה, כמו ספור או ספירה (narratio), ומזה נקראו כן הספרים, מפני שהם כוללים ספור דברים או ספירת דברים.

Comment: I am still trying to learn hebrew with the help of apps. But I cannot read what you wrote. Can you translate for non-Jews. @רבותמחשבות

Comment: @user20490 essentially what he says is exactly the point that Dieter made - namely, that the book must have been a Jewish creation due to the use of the tetragrammaton in it's name.  I'll try to post a translation now:

Comment: Very rough:  Mendelssohn writes that Moses was quoting what had been written in that book, to be a testimony for Israel that they did not enter Moab's borders; and he has not said anything, because according to him that book must have been written by a Jewish person, as it states "that is the well which God said to Moses"; so too, the name of the book (the Wars of Y-H-V-H) shows that it was written by a Jewish person, because the tetragrammaton is specific to the God of Israel,  cont ->

Comment: <- cont and if so, what proof could be brought from that book!?  The correct understanding is that it is not (as Ibn Ezra understands) a book in and of itself, but that it "Sefer" here (as Rashi, Rashbam, and Clericus understand) is a verb, like retelling or counting, and that is why books are called by this as well, since they include retelling things or counting things.

Comment: @Bach This is very interesting although speculative. Notice that I referenced the "burning bush" tradition intimately familiar to Moses, the author. Very roughly, one can skirt this issue only by showing that Moses wasn't the author or that Moses was honoring the Midianite tradition as the true source of the tetragrammaton.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Actually I'm flattered. I wasn't aware of the history of this contemplation, not to mention that my knowledge of Hebrew is at a rank beginner level. Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Comment: @Dieter No problem - great thinking on your part!

Comment: Dieter i agree, and there is good reason to think that Moses is not the author here, for it would be absurd for Moses himself to support his claims regarding the boundaries of Moab when he himself was there. Its like an holocaust survivor who brings scholarly evidence to prove that there was indeed a holocaust. To me it is obvious that it is the work of an Israelite scribe who is referencing another ancient source to provide the support he needs regarding the events that happened in the days of Moses. And it may indeed be an Israelite source.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to add sources as time permits.

This book is not mentioned explicitly anywhere else in the Bible, and there are a number of theories found in the commentaries.

Rashi, Rashbam, Leclerc, and Luzzatto (and presumably many others, all to Numbers 21:14) support the theory that this was not an actual book that was written, but rather it simply refers to this fragment of the Bible narrative.

Among more modern authorities, N. H. Tur Sinai claims [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/23731032?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) that it never existed.

Ibn Ezra to Exodus 17:14 claims that this could have been the book that Moses wrote for Joshua at the battle with Amalek.  However, in Numbers 21:14, he suggests that it may have been written in the times of Abraham.  Similar claims are found in various other commentaries.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_the_Wars_of_the_Lord) quotes David Rosenberg in dating the book to ~1100BC, and Joseph Barber Lightfoot that it is another name for the Biblical [Book of Jasher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Jasher_(biblical_references)).  However, no sources are provided for either claim.)

NZY Berlin suggests that it was a book chronicling the battles fought and happening as the Israelites traveled towards Canaan.

Nahmanides, Abarbanel and Mendelssohn (see Luzatto for a rebuttal) seem to understand that these were books written by other nations at that time about known wars, and that it was not Jewish in nature.

Some understand that it contains mainly events that took place, whereas others seem to understand that it was a book of songs and poetry.

Side note: In [this CBQ article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43713760?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) by Duane Christensen, he attempts to reconstruct the text that we have in order to make any sense out of it, but notes that some have dismissed it as "beyond reconstruction".